# Is Lua 5.3 compatible with Emscripten c++? How do I use it?

Tags: javascript, c++, lua, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to compile a C++ project that uses it but it doesn't work. What compiler flags am I supposed to use?

I'm currently doing

emcc -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s USE_SDL_MIXER=2 -s USE_OGG=1 -s USE_VORBIS=1 -s USE_LUA=53 -o game.html game.cpp

but its not working. The error it says is

fatal error: 'lua.hpp' file not found. how am i supposed to do this?

Comment: I have no experience using emcc. But adding something like -I/path/to/your/hpp might help according to my personal experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that did indeed do the job and get it to compile, but there's another issue. It's saying a lot of errors about "undefined symbol" in the compiler (about lua). How do i put the .lib file in it too? since i assume thats what it needs?

Comment: I added -l "E:\code\LUA\lua53.lib". but this just makes this happen instead
wasm-ld: error: unable to find library -l E:\code\LUA\lua53.lib
Where am I supposed to put the file?
Unless im not understanding this correctly or something

Comment: You'll need to compile lua with emscripten first, you can't link to existing c libraries

Comment: Nevermind. I had to put -llua5.3. That didn't fix the issue though, my current line is

emcc -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s USE_SDL_MIXER=2 -s USE_OGG=1 -s USE_VORBIS=1 -I "E:\code\LUA\include" -llua5.3 -o game.html game.cpp

Comment: Is the `lua53.lib` you use compiled for wasm target? If not, you'll need to manually compile the lua53 source. That might be easy since Lua is written in pure ANSI C.

Comment: Whoops. I didn't see your comment. How do I do that?

Comment: Alright, so i've gotten something called "lua.vm.js" which is apparently the source code of lua 5.3.4 converted for emscripten. I've been trying to compile it, and i've succesfully gotten it to make a lua.vm.js file, how do i make it output a .lib file instead, then how do I later link that file to the original compilation? If required, heres what i mean https://github.com/satoren/lua.vm.js